# Custom taxonomy position in admin panel

Tags: custom-taxonomy, menus, admin

I can't figure out how to change position of custom taxonomy menu item in the admin panel.

Right now I have custom post type-- `custom_1`-- and another custom post type-- `custom_2`.

For custom_2, I've set `'show_in_menu' => 'edit.php?post_type=custom_1'` and it works fine. The problem is, I've added a custom taxonomy for custom_2 and it's not showing under the same parent menu item.

Is there any way to alter the position of custom taxonomy menu item?

Answer (score 3):

It will definately not show in custom_1 because you probably must have defined it for custom_2.However, you can define a custom submenu with link same as that of  the taxonomy in which the parent link is that of custom_2.

Following is what i mean.

```
add_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=custom_1', 'Page Title', 'Menu Title', 'add_users','edit-tags.php?taxonomy=custom_taxonomy', '' );
```

Comment: Pity this isn't marked as accepted because this worked perfectly for me